# Prepared Statement (PHP5, SQLite3) exceeds 30 seconds execution Time

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am trying to avoid duplicate entries of automatically generated random numbers in an SQLite3 DB through PHP. For that i have prepared Statements in a do while loop. The random numbers are generated and then a query checks if the number already exists. If Yes, generate again, if no, carry on.

Atleast, this is what i am trying to achieve...

But for some reason unknown to me, the PHP log keeps showing me that the maximum execution Time of 30 secs has been exeeded at the query line. Firstly, i tried doing the whole thing without prepared statements and it didn't work. I thought that was because i had php variables in the query. So i switched to Prepared Statements without success.

I checked all the POST Variables via Firebug and everything seems to be fine there. It is the Prepared Statement which is giving me diarrhea!!

Can you guys please help me ?

The PHP Code:

```
<?php

$adate    = $_POST['adate'];
$ddate    = $_POST['ddate'];
$ad       = $_POST['ad'];
$dd       = $_POST['dd'];
$fname    = $_POST['fname'];
$lname    = $_POST['lname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$address  = $_POST['address'];
$postal   = $_POST['postal'];
$city     = $_POST['city'];
$country  = $_POST['country'];
$tel      = $_POST['tel'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$price    = $_POST['price'];
$bkfst    = $_POST['bkfst'];
$rnum     = $_POST['rnum'];
$rtype    = $_POST['rtype'];
$robotest = $_POST['blnk'];
$bid      = 0;
$cid      = 0;
$adate    = $adate . " 20:00:00";
$ddate    = $ddate . " 13:00:00";

if ($robotest)
    $error = "You are a gutless robot.";

else {

    function bid()
    {
        $bid = mt_rand(111111, 999999);
        if (($bid % 10) == 0) {
            $bid = $bid + 123;
        }
    }

    function cid()
    {
        $cid = mt_rand(11111, 99999);
        if (($cid % 10) == 0) {
            $cid = $cid + 123;
        }
    }

    include 'connect.php';

    do {
        cid();
    --> $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (CustomerID) from Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?");
        $sth->execute(array($cid));
    } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);

    $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, PostalCode, City, Country, EMail, Phone) VALUES ('$cid', '$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$postal', '$city', '$country', '$email', '$tel')");
    $sth->execute();

    do {
        bid();
    --> $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (BookingID) from Booking WHERE BookingID = ?");
        $sth->execute(array($bid));
    } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);

    $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Booking (BookingID, Arrival, Checkout, RoomNumber, CustomerID, Breakfast, Comment, Paid) VALUES ('$bid', '$adate', '$ddate', '$rnum', '$cid', '$bkfst', '$message', 'N')");
    $sth->execute();

    $subject = "Your Booking";
    $message = "Hi $fname,\n\nA $rtype from $ad to $dd has been booked for you.\n\nYour Booking Code is $bid.\n\nRegards.";

    mail($email, $subject, $message);

    echo 'The Booking completed successfully! Check your E-Mail for further Information.';
}

?>
```

Lines beginning with --> in the code are the problematic lines.

And Yes, I am a Newbie who is learning by doing and also learning by annoying people in the Stack Overflow Forums :)

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is how my Code looks now. All the errors are gone but php is not inserting anything to the DB. The Email is sent correctly with the generated number.

```
<?php

$adate    = $_POST['adate'];
$ddate    = $_POST['ddate'];
$ad       = $_POST['ad'];
$dd       = $_POST['dd'];
$fname    = $_POST['fname'];
$lname    = $_POST['lname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$address  = $_POST['address'];
$postal   = $_POST['postal'];
$city     = $_POST['city'];
$country  = $_POST['country'];
$tel      = $_POST['tel'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$price    = $_POST['price'];
$bkfst    = $_POST['bkfst'];
$rnum     = $_POST['rnum'];
$rtype    = $_POST['rtype'];
$robotest = $_POST['blnk'];
$adate    = $adate . " 20:00:00";
$ddate    = $ddate . " 13:00:00";
$cid;
$bid;

if ($robotest)
    $error = "You are a gutless robot.";

else {

    function bid()
    {
        global $bid;
        $bid = mt_rand(111111, 999999);
        if (($bid % 10) == 0) {
            $bid = $bid + 123;

        }
    }

    function cid()
    {
        global $cid;
        $cid = mt_rand(11111, 99999);
        if (($cid % 10) == 0) {
            $cid = $cid + 123;

        }
    }

    include 'connect.php';

    do {
        global $cid;
        cid();
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (CustomerID) from Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?');
        $sth->execute(array($cid));
        } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);


    global $cid;
    $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, PostalCode, City, Country, EMail, Phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $sth->execute(array($cid, $fname, $lname, $address, $postal, $city, $country, $email, $tel));

    do {
        global $bid;
        bid();
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (BookingID) from Booking WHERE BookingID = ?');
        } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);


    global $bid;
    global $cid;
    $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Booking (BookingID, Arrival, Checkout, RoomNumber, CustomerID, Breakfast, Comment, Paid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $sth->execute(array($bid, $adate, $ddate, $rnum, $cid, $bkfst, $message, 'N'));


    $subject = "Your Booking";
    global $bid;
    $message = "Hi $fname,\n\nA $rtype from $ad to $dd has been booked for you.\n\nYour Booking Code is $bid.\n\nRegards.";
    mail($email, $subject, $message);


    echo 'The Booking completed successfully! Check your E-Mail for further Information.';
}

?>
```

hhmmm...

Comment: Why do you need unique random numbers?

Comment: Why aren't you parameterizing everywhere?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope... the `$cid()` and `$bid` inside your functions are **NOT** the cid/big you define earlier. Since the "inside" variables are destroyed when the functions return, the functions are essentially useless. you need to have a `global $bid`, or have them RETURN the new values, and have `$cid = cid()` everywhere you want those values.

Comment: Anyway, since you're not answering my question and I have to go, I wanted to recommend http://hashids.org/ to you instead of doing it like this. Just use a regular auto-increment index and then use hashids to get a unique id of that index (using the characters of your choice) that the user is unable to convert back to the index without knowing your secret key.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `prepare()` inside the loop. You prepare the statement once, then execute it multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: @Mike I am not using hashid because i don't want the id to be any longer than 6 digits for bid and 5 digits for cid. Hashid generates an id which is way too long.

Comment: @Zombievirus The ID with hashids can actually be configured to be shorter than its decimal equivalent for all numbers larger than around 3 digits. See http://pastebin.com/rGyMuEfB. How you are doing it now becomes more and more inefficient when you get more ids, and when it finally becomes saturated you go into an infinite loop. If you're not going to do it with something like hashids, I recommend adding another table with pre-randomized values so all you have to do is pick the next one and you don't have to worry about it being a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop:

```
do {
    cid();
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (CustomerID) from Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($cid));
} while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);
```

Since your cid/bid() functions are badly constructed, the `$cid` you're using inside this do() loop will **NEVER**  change from the `$cid = 0` you did at the top of the script.

So the loop starts, you prepare/execute the query with `CustomerID = 0`, get back one of row of data with the count() results, which you fetch.

Then the loop rolls around again, and you RE-EXECUTE the query, with the exact same $cid = 0 value, so you continue reset the loop termination condition - you never end up with a value, because you keep query with the same bad/invalid cid=0.

It's pretty much the same like the good old BASIC program: `10 GOTO 10`.

Comment: I thought, i already declared them globally by doing `$cid=0;` in the beginning. How do i use the global `$cid` inside a function, if not the way i did it here?

Comment: @Zombievirus You need to put `global $cid;` inside the `cid()` function, and `global $bid;` inside the `bid()` function.

Comment: yup, that i figured out and now the exceeding error is gone but i am now trying to figure out how to use global variables in the insert statement...

Comment: no, just declaring a variable at the top scopes does **NOT** make them visible in lower scopes. That's never worked in PHP. you have to explicitly declare a variable "global" inside functions, which makes those top-level vars visible inside the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I corrected a few things in my code. the errors are gone but nothing is being inserted to the DB. I edited my post above with the corrected Code.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now:

```
<?php

$adate    = $_POST['adate'];
$ddate    = $_POST['ddate'];
$ad       = $_POST['ad'];
$dd       = $_POST['dd'];
$fname    = $_POST['fname'];
$lname    = $_POST['lname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$address  = $_POST['address'];
$postal   = $_POST['postal'];
$city     = $_POST['city'];
$country  = $_POST['country'];
$tel      = $_POST['tel'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$price    = $_POST['price'];
$bkfst    = $_POST['bkfst'];
$rnum     = $_POST['rnum'];
$rtype    = $_POST['rtype'];
$robotest = $_POST['blnk'];
$adate    = $adate . " 20:00:00";
$ddate    = $ddate . " 13:00:00";
$cid;
$bid;

if ($robotest)
    $error = "You are a gutless robot.";

else {

    function bid()
    {
        global $bid;
        $bid = mt_rand(111111, 999999);
        if (($bid % 10) == 0) {
            $bid = $bid + 123;

        }
    }

    function cid()
    {
        global $cid;
        $cid = mt_rand(11111, 99999);
        if (($cid % 10) == 0) {
            $cid = $cid + 123;

        }
    }

    include 'connect.php';

    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (EMail) from Customer WHERE EMail = ?');
    $sth->execute(array($email));
    if($sth->fetchColumn() < 1){

    do {
        global $cid;
        cid();
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (CustomerID) from Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?');
        $sth->execute(array($cid));
        } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);

    global $cid;
    $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, PostalCode, City, Country, EMail, Phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $sth->execute(array($cid, $fname, $lname, $address, $postal, $city, $country, $email, $tel));   

    }else{
    global $cid;    
    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT CustomerID from Customer WHERE EMail = ?');
    $sth->execute(array($email));
    $id = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cid = $id['CustomerID'];
    }

    do {
        global $bid;
        bid();
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (BookingID) from Booking WHERE BookingID = ?');
        } while ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0);


    global $bid;
    global $cid;
    $booktime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Booking (BookingID, Arrival, Checkout, RoomNumber, CustomerID, Breakfast, Comment, Paid, BookTime, Invoice) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $sth->execute(array($bid, $adate, $ddate, $rnum, $cid, $bkfst, $message, 'N', $booktime, NULL));


    $subject = "Your Booking";
    global $bid;
    $message = "Hi $fname,\n\nA $rtype from $ad to $dd has been booked for you.\n\nYour Booking Code is $bid.\n\nMention this Code if you need to get in touch with us.\n\nRegards.";
    mail($email, $subject, $message);


    echo 'The Booking completed successfully! Check your E-Mail for further Information.';
}

?>
```

No Clue, if this is the best way to do it but it is working perfectly.

Thanks for all the hints.